# Windows 10 iot core UWP bluetooth sound connection

Tags: uwp, bluetooth, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core, windows-iot-core-10

I want to connect bluetooth headset, headphone, speakers to my uwp application. I can list all bluetooth devices and I can pair to clicked one but I couldn't manage to connect sound device (pairing is successful but can't transfer sound and when paired no response from sound device). Is it possible to do that ? What's my mistake ?
Thanks

Comment: Which version of Windows IoT Core and what device were you using? For Build 17763.253, RPi3 will not pair BT + BTLE with onboard Bluetooth.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT I have 17763.615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, Windows IoT Core does not support bluetooch sound connection, since Windows IoT Core does not implement the A2DP (Advanced Audio Distribution Profile) Profile and stream audio to a head set  that implements the HSP (Headset) Profile OBEX (Object Exchange) is a symmetric connection between two devices as they exchange data between them. Windows IoT Core uses the GATT (Generic Attribute Profile Profile).This provides profile discovery and description services for  the Bluetooth Low Energy protocol.With this protocol simple low power devices can be connected at one end generating data to be consumed by a complex processor.